# Can I store debitcard information in the PayPal vault api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting the "invalid number" error while save the debit card information using pay pal sandbox account

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you are attempting to save a live card in the sandbox environment.